# Does the answer key contain a typo?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm given two coordinates:

(1,2) and (1 + 3t, 3 + t)

And then I'm asked to find the distance between them. I use Pythagorean formula and solve the distance to:

√(3t² + (1 + t)²)

But the answer key says the answer is:

√(10t² + 2t + 1)

Yet in the answer key it also says that the change of x is (3t) and that the change of y is (1 + t) hence my squaring of these values in my formula. In my answer I know I did not factor but I still think the answer key is wrong and meant to say

√(4t² + 2t + 1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost right! The mistake you made is that you wrote $3t^2$ instead of $(3t)^2$.

(Good job asking the question, by the way, to make it easy for us to diagnose the issue.)

Comment: Damnit. That's so annoying I missed that! Thank you!